# not able to get the image from django backend to phonegap android application using ajax

Tags: android, jquery, ajax, django, cordova

I am building the android application using the phonegap. I am using django backend for android application.

Here i am trying to get the all details of book model, but i am not getting the image in front end but remaining all data for that model i am getting.

i am using

```
html = render_to_string('crave/book/book.html',{"books":books})
return HttpResponse(html,mimetype="application/json")
```

to get the data to front end using ajax.

here my book.html file

```
{% for book in books  %}
<img style="padding:1%;float:left;" src="/media/{{book.image}}" height="195" width="140"/>
         </div>
         <div class="span8" style="background-color:black; ">
         <em style="color:red;font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;font-size:1em;">{{book.title}}</em><p style="font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; font-size:0.7em;">{{ book.discription }}
         <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <div id="f" style="padding-top: 3%;padding-bottom: 1%; background-color:black;">
        <div class="container" align="left" style="background-color:black; ">
            <div class="col-lg-4 " style="font-size:0.9em;font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;">
            add button
            <a href="#" align="right" style="color:red; font-size:0.9em;font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif; float:right;" id="repcrave" class="cli">By {{ book.author }}</a></div>
            </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

here i am getting all the details like title, author, discription in phonegap application through ajax but only image i am not able to get. 
I checked image is saved in the path specified above

when i do this in browser in django application

```
return render(request, "crave/book/book.html", {'books':books})
```

i am able to get the image for django application.

here is my ajax to get the html in android application.

```
$(function () 
         {  
                var domain = localStorage['domain'];
                $.ajax({
                    url: domain + "/book/books/",
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: 'html',
                    success: function (html) {

                                $('#speicificpost_reply').html(html);
                            },
                        error: function (response) {
                        alert('You dont have your books here');

                        }
                });
        });
```

i dont know what wrong i am doing here. If any one gone through before please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically emulator won't recognize "localhost" in emulator browser.So we have to use IP address of system.In this problem simply use `http://192.168.0.1/media/{{book.image}}` in src attribute.Here 192.168.0.1 is my system IP address.

Comment: Hi Ramakrishna, the best approach is to use `{{ book.image.url }}` instead of `http://192.168.0.1/media/{{book.image}}`, then in settings.MEDIA_URL you configure `http://192.168.0.1/media/`. This way, changing settings you'll get the new url in all templates.

Answer (score -1):

In django itself you can get the image by specifying the media path over there. like /media/{{image}}

but for phone gap you need to specify the full path including domain also. While you are getting the image in to the phone gap application it need to be have the full path of that image because the is no media_url setting available like its in django settings file.